RNN invalidArgumentError
I am training RNN model for speech to text purpose.
While training RNN, I am getting this weird error called invalid argument error indices[28,0] = -1 is not in [0,169)
model = keras.Sequential()

# Add an embeddings layers
model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim = 13*13, output_dim = 32, input_length = 13*13))
#model.add(layers.Flatten())
# add an RNN layer
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(64,activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))
# add dense layers
model.add(layers.Dense(11))

model.summary()


My input is of shape (100,13,13) and target shape is (100,11) for training.
What does this error exactly means? Is this points out error in data or model architecture?
I am trying to resolve this error by adjusting dimension in RNN model. But I am facing this error first time and have no idea about it
